# Libgit2 difficulty merging

Tags: qt, libgit2

I'm trying to merge another branch into my own branch using Libgit2. It runs with no error code, however when I actually look at the files the merge appears not to have taken place. This is my code:

```
    git_commit * commit = NULL; /* the result */
git_oid oid_parent_commit;  /* the SHA1 for last commit */

int error = git_reference_name_to_id(&oid_parent_commit, repo, branchToReferenceMap.value("master"));
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);
git_commit *lastCommit;
if (error == 0)
{
    /* get the actual commit structure */
    error = git_commit_lookup(&commit, repo, &oid_parent_commit);
    if (error == 0)
    {
        lastCommit = getLastCommit(repo, "master");
    }
}
else 
    return;


git_annotated_commit *heads;

git_commit *lastCommit = getLastCommit(repo, "master");
const git_oid *id = git_commit_id(lastCommit);

int error = git_annotated_commit_lookup(&heads, repo, id);
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);


git_merge_options opts;
git_checkout_options checkOpts;
error = git_merge_init_options(&opts, GIT_MERGE_FILE_OPTIONS_VERSION);
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);    
error = git_checkout_init_options(&checkOpts, GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_VERSION);
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);



error = git_merge(repo, const_cast<const git_annotated_commit**>(&heads), 1, &opts, &checkOpts);
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);

error = git_repository_state_cleanup(repo);
if (error < 0)
    errorMessage(error);
```

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't take place?  What's in your index?